# Necesito un array como resultado

Tags: python, array, numpy

En el siguiente codigo tengo una lista de salida. Los elementos de esta lista son correctos, pero necesito que sea un np.array().

```
p =np.array([[1,2],[3,1],[2,-1],[2,5],[0,1],[4,2],[1,0],[3,3],[0,4],[2,2],[3.5,1],[3.5,5],[2,3],[1,5],[1.5,3]])

c =np.array([[1,1.5],[3,1.5],[1,3]])


a.DI()

array([[0.5       , 2.06155281, 2.6925824 , 3.64005494, 1.11803399,
    3.04138127, 1.5       , 2.5       , 2.6925824 , 1.11803399,
    2.54950976, 4.30116263, 1.80277564, 3.5       , 1.58113883],
   [2.06155281, 0.5       , 2.6925824 , 3.64005494, 3.04138127,
    1.11803399, 2.5       , 1.5       , 3.90512484, 1.11803399,
    0.70710678, 3.53553391, 1.80277564, 4.03112887, 2.12132034],
   [1.        , 2.82842712, 4.12310563, 2.23606798, 2.23606798,
    3.16227766, 3.        , 2.        , 1.41421356, 1.41421356,
    3.20156212, 3.20156212, 1.        , 2.        , 0.5       ]])

KC = [[]] * len(c)
for i in range(len(c)):
    KC[i] = []
for i in range(len(p)):
    KC[np.where(a.DI()[:,i] == np.min(a.DI()[:,i]))[0][0]].append(p[i])
```

con esto el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
[[array([1., 2.]),
array([ 2., -1.]),
array([0., 1.]),
array([1., 0.]),
array([2., 2.])],
[array([3., 1.]), array([4., 2.]), array([3., 3.]), array([3.5, 1. ])],
[array([2., 5.]),
 array([0., 4.]),
array([3.5, 5. ]),
array([2., 3.]),
array([1., 5.]),
array([1.5, 3. ])]]
```

y lo que espero es:

```
[array([[ 1.,  2.],
    [ 2., -1.],
    [ 0.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  0.],
    [ 2.,  2.]]), array([[3. , 1. ],
    [4. , 2. ],
    [3. , 3. ],
    [3.5, 1. ]]), array([[2. , 5. ],
    [0. , 4. ],
    [3.5, 5. ],
    [2. , 3. ],
    [1. , 5. ],
    [1.5, 3. ]]), array([], shape=(0L, 2L), dtype=float64)]
```

De primera mano, pensé que sería simple de resolver pero no doy con la solución.
Intente con la función "np.concatenate()" pero no he logrado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que buscas es el método [`numpy.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html), el cual permite unir una secuencia de arrays en un eje determinado:

```
import numpy as np
from types import SimpleNamespace

p = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 1], [2,  -1], [2,   5], [0, 1], [4, 2], [1,   0], [3, 3],
              [0, 4], [2, 2], [3.5, 1], [3.5, 5], [2, 3], [1, 5], [1.5, 3]]
             )

c = np.array([[1, 1.5], [3, 1.5], [1, 3]])


a = SimpleNamespace(DI=lambda:
    np.array([[0.5       , 2.06155281, 2.6925824 , 3.64005494, 1.11803399,
               3.04138127, 1.5       , 2.5       , 2.6925824 , 1.11803399,
               2.54950976, 4.30116263, 1.80277564, 3.5       , 1.58113883],
              [2.06155281, 0.5       , 2.6925824 , 3.64005494, 3.04138127,
               1.11803399, 2.5       , 1.5       , 3.90512484, 1.11803399,
               0.70710678, 3.53553391, 1.80277564, 4.03112887, 2.12132034],
              [1.        , 2.82842712, 4.12310563, 2.23606798, 2.23606798,
               3.16227766, 3.        , 2.        , 1.41421356, 1.41421356,
               3.20156212, 3.20156212, 1.        , 2.        , 0.5       ]])
    )

KC = [[] for _ in range(c.shape[0])]
min_idxs = a.DI().argmin(axis=0)
for arr, idx in zip(p, min_idxs):
    KC[idx].append(arr)

KC = [np.stack(x) for x in KC]
```

La salida es:

> ```
> >>> KC
>
> [array([[ 1.,  2.],
>         [ 2., -1.],
>         [ 0.,  1.],
>         [ 1.,  0.],
>         [ 2.,  2.]]),
>  array([[ 3. , 1.],
>         [ 4. , 2.],
>         [ 3. , 3.],
>         [ 3.5, 1.]]),
>  array([[ 2. , 5.],
>         [ 0. , 4.],
>         [ 3.5, 5.],
>         [ 2. , 3.],
>         [ 1. , 5.],
>         [ 1.5, 3.]])]
> ```

La obtención del índice del menor elemento por columna se puede simplificar usando `numpy.argmin` como muestro en el ejemplo.

Comment: Wow !! me pondre a estudiar las nuevas funciones! Muchas gracias !!

Comment: Ahora que lo veo es una belleza tu solucion!!!! muy util zip(,)!